# Django rest framework post request while using ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django have background in Node.js.

I am creating an API using **Django**, **Django rest framework** and **PostgreSQL**.

```
# Model for Event.

class Event(models.Model):
    heading = models.TextField()
    event_posted_by = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events_posted', null=True)
    event_construction_site = models.ForeignKey(
        ConstructionSite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='construction_site_events', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)



# Event ViewSet 

class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

# Event Serializer

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_construction_site = ConstructionSiteShortSerializer()
    event_posted_by = CustomUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'heading',
                  'event_posted_by', 'event_construction_site')
```

Everything here works fine and expected as well.

Here is the output of my `GET Request`.

```
   {
        "id": 2,
        "heading": "ABCD",
        "event_posted_by": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "A",
            "last_name": "B",
            "profile_picture": "...",
            "company": {
               "id": 3,
               "name": "Company 3"
             },
        },
        "event_construction_site": {
            "id": 2
        }
    },
```

But now when it comes to create an event this is the view **django rest framework** shows me.

```
{
    "heading": "",
    "event_posted_by": {
        "email": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "company": {
            "name": ""
        },
        "profile_picture": "",
        "user_construction_site": []
    },
    "event_construction_site": {}
}
```

Here as far as I know when need `"event_posted_by"` by in GET Request but we don't want to post the user info. while creating an event, same for information inside user like `user_construction_site` here the only behaviour I want is to send the User `ID` to backend and somehow in my `class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)` handle this post request and map  `"event_posted_by"` to user data by using user `ID` sent from client side.

How these kind of problems are genrally handeled in DRF by creating different **read / write serailizers**?

Comment: Have you read this : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches thanks I got that part applying read_only=True solved the problem of showing event_posted_by in the post request payload, now my Question is what if I want to post the ID of event_construction_site  user belongs to but somehow my post request fails and doesn't allow me to write that field with event_construction_site ID, would be great if you can tell how these kind of situations are handled?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want... can you edit your post with an example detailling every step of your process ?

Comment: @BriseBallochesI Thanks. :) I posted another Question for the same as I consider that as different problem here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373433/update-foreign-key-in-django-rest-framework-model-using-viewsets-modelviewset-vi

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem by following suggestion by @BriseBalloches in the comment above.

In summary updated the `event_posted_by` by adding a `read_only` key.

`event_posted_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)`