# Update foreign key in Django rest framework model using viewsets.ModelViewSet view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am relatively new to DRF and having hard time updating the **foreign key** in my model via **POST** request.

```
    # Model for Event.

        class Event(models.Model):
              heading = models.TextField()
              event_construction_site = models.ForeignKey(
                  ConstructionSite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='construction_site_events', null=True)
            
              def __str__(self):
                  return str(self.id)
    
    
        class ConstructionSiteShortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = ConstructionSite
                fields = ['id']
    
     # Serializer for Event.

        class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            event_construction_site = ConstructionSiteShortSerializer()
            event_posted_by = CustomUserSerializer()
        
            class Meta:
                model = Event
                fields = ('id', 'heading', 'event_construction_site')
```

Structure of my `GET` response is as follows:

```
  {
    id: 1,
    heading: "Truck with formwork arrived",
    event_construction_site: {
      id: 3
    }
  }
```

My concern here is how can I update the `id` of `event_construction_site`?

I tried updating it like as follows:

```
{
    "heading": "a",
    "event_construction_site": {"id": 2}
}
```

Dute to `id` of `event_construction_site` being nested field I get an error that says =>

```
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The \`.create()\` method does not support writable nested fields by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394761/the-create-method-does-not-support-writable-nested-fields-by-default)

Comment: I looked into it @DušanMaďar but had a thought that whether just to updated an ID field do we need to do method overiding? or is there any other way we can achieve the same, in my case if updating an id requires me to overide create & to_representation method then it doesn't make much sense as I have to do this in almost all of my views as I have nested data present in all of them.

Comment: Why do you not use a PrimaryKeyRelatedField instead of your event_construction_site serializer. I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: @BriseBallochesgood suggestion that won't solve becuase if I use it I gest this err => AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True` , and if I set  read_only=`True` to true then event_construction_site won't appear in my POST payload.

Comment: Just add the argument queryset=ConstructionSite.objects.all() to PrimaryKeyRelatedField.

Comment: @BriseBalloches It worked like charm thanks a lot!  you can post it as a answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PrimaryKeyRelatedField.

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            event_construction_site = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ConstructionSite.objects.all())
            event_posted_by = CustomUserSerializer()
        
            class Meta:
                model = Event
                fields = ('id', 'heading', 'event_construction_site')
```